# When CDialog.DoModal() function fails to create dialog box?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc

MSDN said, for the CDialog.DoModal() function, the return value is –1 if the function could not create the dialog box. It does not say in which case it could fail to create the dialog box.

A quick investigation into MFC source code shows if the (LPCDLGTEMPLATE)LockResource(hDialogTemplate) returns NULL, the DoModal function could return -1.

Since my problem cannot be reproduced stably in our stress test, I cannot debug the program to find the root cause. Did anybody here meet similar problem?

Comment: you _had_ to use MFC, didn't you?

Comment: @IntermediateHacker, let's not turn this in to a "that API sucks, why use it" debate, we'll be here all day.

Comment: @Moo-Juice yeah, but I have seriously bad memories with the API in question. It gives me the creeps.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot what event log or GetLastError says. It is my fault. The best way to raise such questions is to collect all the error report together and paste them here. Thanks for inspiring me.

Answer (score 5):

`DoModal()` relies on the [CreateDialogIndirect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645436.aspx) API function. The documentation for its cousin [DialogBox()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452.aspx) states that function can fail under the following circumstances:

> - an invalid parameter value,
> - the system class was registered by a different module,
> - the `WH_CBT` hook is installed and returns a failure code,
> - one of the controls in the dialog template is not registered, or its window procedure fails on `WM_CREATE` or `WM_NCCREATE`.

I personally never encountered the first three reasons, but I was bitten once by the fourth because my dialog box contained an ActiveX control that was not registered on the machine. Maybe you're experiencing the same issue.

Comment: MFC doesn't use `DialogBox`, it simulates it with other calls. Some of the information in this answer is still useful though.

Comment: @Mark, you're absolutely right, it uses `CreateDialogIndirect()` even for modal dialogs, and implements the modal state itself. I wonder why, but there's probably a good reason. Thank you for your clarification :)

Comment: I had the DoModal call failing after changing locale: the new resource missed some ids the original resource had. I report this hoping to give hint to others in similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause comes from the exhausted GDI objects. Our software exists handle leaks. The max number of GDI objects can be set in registry. The value is 16000 in our Windows XP. I wrote a program to create lots of UI controls and not to free them. By this way I can simulate the GDI handle exhausting situation. As a result, the same problem is reproduced again.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\GDIProcessHandleQuota

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

So is it the final conclusion that when the GDI objects are exhausted, some UI controls such as CDialog, would be failed to create?

Comment: Handles exhausting is a well known issue on Win32 when running/debugging applications with complex GUI (CAD, EDA). On Win64 we didn't expect Out of Handles issue.